# Is it possible to simultaneously combine Play and Say verbs

Tags: twilio

The use case I'd like to create is to have some background audio play over a voiceover as part of an introduction to an IVR.  Is it possible to combine the  and  verb at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It's not possible to [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play) and [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say) at the same time. If you're after a message playing over music then I recommend you record the message and audio into the same audio file and play it with [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play). That way you can guarantee the quality of the audio and voice together.